# Make simple icons larger without losing quality in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, flat-design

*I couldn't find an answer to my question, probably because this is so basic.*

How could I make a simple 2 colored flat icon 2 times larger in Photoshop (CC) without making it blurry?

[image: Small icon]
[image: 2x icon]

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, as this is not a .jpeg image, but a simple flat icon, that could easily be vectorized with Illustrator, but I'm looking for a Photoshop solution.

Comment: There is no Photoshop solution. it doesn't **not** matter if it's a jpg photo, a png icon, a gif illustration... its all *raster* content and there's no way to increase the dimensions of a raster image without losing quality. The *only* solution would be to recreate the content as vectors.

Comment: Scott is correct...though you can make it less blurry by increasing the curves and/or contrast in Photoshop. However, you will still have a large loss of definition since you're at the mercy of Photoshop trying to make pixels appear that simply didn't exist before.

Comment: @DA01 It sure sounds weird that an advanced software like Photoshop cannot see that there is only white pixels and reproduce them when resizing...

Comment: @Claudio the pixels don't exist. It has to assume where the missing pixels need to be added. Software is only so smart. FYI, there's a lot more than two colors of pixels there.

Comment: @DA01 The result still looks the same whether it's 4 (including transparency) or 256 color GIF.

Comment: You can pretty much always assume that upsizing a raster image is not an option. Sometimes you can get away with it, but usually that is only acceptable if there are no other options. You could try all the tricks to upsize this example image and it would never be very crisp ( at that size anyways ). However, you could re-create it in Illustrator or some other vector based application in a few minutes and then use that at any size. That is just how it is.

Comment: @Claudio I'm not sure what you mean. If you start with 100 pixels, and ask software to create an image with 200 pixels, those extra 100 pixels have to come from somewhere. Photoshop does the best it can trying to best-guess what those 100 extra pixels should be and where they should go. But it can only do so much.

Comment: @DA01 I was trying to tell that from all of its advanced features, can't it guess that it only includes white pixels and create more of white pixels properly? I'm not a programmer, so I don't know how hard (or possible) it is, but in logic it seems easy.

Comment: @Claudio This isn't bad CSI TV where they can zoom into an image 10000x and read the license plate being reflected off of someone's contact lenses. :) That doesn't actually exist. So, unfortunately, no, Photoshop can't read our minds when blowing up images...it has to guess based on some logic. Again, however, note that it's not 'just white pixels' your image is dealing with. Zoom in on your image and you'll notice there are dozens of colors that form the edges of the lines. It's a much ore complex image that it at first appears.

Comment: @Claudio - here is something you can try.. a raster upscale technique that works pretty good on icons that don't have any sharp edges.. like your icon. resize your icon to 2000x2000 using bicubic interpolation. do image>adjustments>threshold and put it at 240. do filter>blur>gaussian blur and put it at 20 pixels. do image>adjustments>threshold again and put it at 120. when you scale back down to you'll be left with a shape that is pretty good. you will need to draw the circle around it again and colorize it of course. that's what i'd do anyway.